# Can I add my University to My E-mail Signiture?

Tags: email

Would it be professional to add my university to my e-mail signature? The format would look something like this:

Alexander Dumas, M.A., PhD.

University of Chicago

I would like to add more than just my name to a signature.

Comment: Why do you ask? You can add whatever you want.

Comment: @MaskedMan Because in academia we typically do not list our undergrad degree, only our grad and/or doc. degrees. There is a format, and I want to make sure that my e-mails remain professional.

Comment: Well, then looks like you have to make a choice between following the conventional format or your own. It is still not clear to me what help you need here from us.

Comment: I was asking if it was professional, or made that assumption that others would understand the question. @keshlam If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the chosen answer.

Comment: @Nicholas If you're talking about [Academia.se] then you're on the wrong site.

Comment: @Nicholas I only look at signatures for contact information. I couldn't care less if you went to Harvard or Jupiter.

Comment: If you wrote "Harvard University" in your email signature, I'd assume you worked there. When I found out you didn't, my assessment of you would end up in the toilet. Do NOT do this to indicate where your degree is from -- it'd make you look like a huge tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you teaching, or a student? If the latter, I would add something like "MS candidate, class of 'XX", to clarify the statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can put anything you want in your signature. Doesn't even have to be factual. Getting it taken seriously is another matter.

Comment: Do you think it is irrelevant, and people do not care where I went to uni?

Comment: How would I know what your friends like, it's purely up to you. I have an email signature on one email address that I use to register online with that says I'm a cleaner on the Starship Enterprise.

Comment: @Nicholas people do not care where you went to college. They Only exception might be is if you work there currently